# How to subtract 3 months from January to get right month?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to calculate year and month in my web application.

In my code, I have year `201604`. I want to subtract the month by 3, So it should be 201601. I got this part work but now if I want to subtract another 3 monyths from `201601` again, the result should be `201511`. I am not sure how to do this part. Help will be appreciated

Code

```
decimal str = "201604";
decimal year= (decimal) Calculations.ParseStringToDecimal(str.SubString(0,4), 0);
decimal month = (decimal) Calculations.ParseStringToDecimal(str.SubString(4,2), 0);

newMonth = month - 3; 

string newDate = year + month

//Result: 201601. 

//I want to subtract 201601 again, then the result should be 201511.
```

Comment: why not using datetime class?

Comment: I'd advise you to look at `DateTime` for doing Date calculations.

Comment: You need to take you integer values and turn them into actual dates then `.AddMonths(-3)`

Comment: You should be using a datetime object. This has all the methods you need

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905443/subtract-2-datetime-fields-to-get-the-days-left-difference

Comment: `decimal str = "201604";` won't compile either..

Comment: Umm. Interesting @Liam, I think AddMonths(-3) would do. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When working with *dates* use `DateTime` class which has been *specially designed* for this purpose:

```
  String str = "201604";

  DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .AddMonths(-3);

  // 201601
  String newDate = date.ToString("yyyyMM");
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. Just a question, somehow I got Cannot use "DateTime" variable before it is declare. Why's that?

Comment: @DragonBorn: You have a *syntax error* in your code: `DateTime` is *class*, not a *variable*; you may have put a erroneous `;` like that `DateTime; date` instead of right `DateTime date`. If you want a solution, not just a guess, please, provide your code.

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime threemonthprevDate = DateTime.ParseExact(str,"yyyyMM",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddMonths(-3);

DateTime sixmonthprevDate = threemonthprevDate.AddMonths(-3));
```

Use ParseExact method instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
string str = "201604";
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(int.Parse(str.Substring(0, 4)), int.Parse(str.Substring(4, 2)), 1);
dateTime = dateTime.AddMonths(-3);
string resultString = dateTime.ToString("yyyyMM");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "201604";
decimal year= (decimal) Calculations.ParseStringToDecimal(str.SubString(0,4), 0);
decimal month = (decimal) Calculations.ParseStringToDecimal(str.SubString(4,2), 0);
DateTime dateObj = new Date(year, month, 1);
dateObj.AddMonths(-3);
//201601
string newDate1 = dateObj.ToString("yyyyMM");
dateObj.AddMonths(-3);
//201511
string newDate1 = dateObj.ToString("yyyyMM");
```