# Calculate a Future Date in Memory in WinForms

Tags: winforms, date, datetimepicker

I have a Date in DateTimePicker I want to add say x no of days and then compare it with todays date in an if statement

Please Help me in Calculating the Date i.e how to add no of days to a Date

Please Help,Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [AddDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) method

Assuming you know how to get the DateTime from the datePicker,

```
DateTime dateFromPicker = DateTime.Now;
DateTime tomorrow = dateFromPicker.AddDays(1);
Console.WriteLine(tomorrow.ToString());
```

Comment: what does Console.WriteLine do

Comment: Console.WriteLine just prints to console. And yes, future date will be in 'tomorrow'

Comment: also how to find the No of days between two dates

Comment: RTFM. If you think this answer sufficiently answers your question, mark it as resolved and move on!

Comment: I know that , I will mark it as an answer.. But i m having some problem so help me =  how to find the No of days between two dates

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839025/c-sharp-difference-between-two-dates. Check this out. Has what you need